# Shaking, misfiring with all new parts and sensors in a Chevy Cruze 2012 turbo 4 cylinder

Tags: chevrolet, turbocharger, cruze

I just had my 2012 chevy Cruze 4 cylinder turbo spark plugs, coil pack, MAP sensor, and pressure sensor replaced all same time and my car drove nicely around the corner but as soon as I pulled up to the red light, the check engine light came on and the stabilizer traction light came on. What's happening with my car?

Comment: Have you taken it back to where you had the parts fitted?

Comment: Engine light means that diagnostic codes are waiting to be read. They usually tell at least part of the story. Of course, the usual suspects are low quality parts or mechanic's mistakes while installing them. What was the reason of replacing all these things in the first place? Did the car run normally before the repair?

Comment: If it ran fine for a little bit after installation,  more than likely an electrical connection came loose (recheck all connections) or one of the new parts failed. As @fraxinus stated ... read the codes. This will usually point out what's wrong.